# Show that $P[A_k\cap B]\leq (1-e^{-1})\lambda$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have a graph $G$ with $k$ vertices, where $k>2$ is a fixed positive integer. At every step, we choose a vertex $v$ uniformly among the $k$ vertices and perform some operation on it.

$B$ is the event that I perform operation $B$ on a randomly chosen vertex $v$. We also have $P(B)\leq \lambda$ given where $\lambda$ is some fixed real number in $[0,1]$ independent of $v$.

$A_k$ is the event that I select vertex $v$ at least once in the first $k$ step of my procedure. Once I perform an operation on a vertex $v$, $v$ retains that operation until the next time we select $v$ and perform the operation on $v$ again. So, at the end of $k$ steps, $v$ has the operation done on it the last time it was selected among the $k$ vertices in the $k$ steps.

I want to show $P[A_k\cap B]\leq (1-e^{-1})\lambda$.

I don't know how to get $(1-e^{-1})$. I have worked out that $P[v$ was selected in some of the $k$ steps$]\geq 1-e^{-1}$. But that's a lower bound!

Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - when you select the vertex, you preform the operation on it? Doesn't that mean that $B\subset A_k$?

Comment: Think of $B$ as colouring a vertex in some way such that something is accomplished. It has a probability of its own (details I believe are irrelevant for this particular inequality). Then is it true that $B\subset A_k$?

Comment: Is it known that the selection and the operation are independent?

Comment: I'll give a brief sketch of the original problem: You have two graphs with $k$ vertices where no two neighbouring vertices have same colour. You choose a vertex randomly, check its neighbours in first graph, and assign a colour; you look at that vertex in the second graph, check its neighbours, and assign a colour. $B$ is the event that these two colours are different. $A_k$ is the event that you selected vertex $v$ at some step in steps $1,2,...,k$. So $A_k\cap B$ is the event that the "last" time you changed colour of $v$, the colours do not match.

Comment: So just because colours do not match, I cannot say that $v$ was selected at some point. It may be that the two starting graphs are different, there colours did not match, and $v$ was not selected at all, still at the end of $k$ steps colours of $v$ in the two graphs are different.